# How to pass the sonar properties for a gradle project to SonarLint

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to configure SonarLint for a gradle project in Eclipse.
How can I  pass the sonar properties through a property file in the project. I don't want to set them through the properties dialogue.

Comment: Which properties do you want to pass? In any case, it is no longer possible to define properties in a file.

Comment: SonarLint is looking for the test results in /target folder but for Gradle project they will be available under /build. I want to configure the location. I have many sub modules in my gradle project. I don't want to set it manually for all the projects in eclipse every time I import.